# MySQL Order By date column and integer column, but specify ordering rules of integer column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, case

I have the following table:

```
-----------------------------------
  PK       integer          date
-----------------------------------
  1          2             03/01/01
  2          1             04/01/01
  3          3             02/01/01
  4          3             05/01/01
  5          2             01/01/01
  6          1             06/01/01
```

What I want to do is to order by the date column, BUT have the dates with integer 2 higher up the order than the other integers. My output would be like this.

```
-----------------------------------
  PK       integer          date
-----------------------------------
  1          2             01/01/01
  5          2             03/01/01      
  3          3             02/01/01
  2          1             04/01/01
  4          3             05/01/01
  6          1             06/01/01
```

At the moment I'm totally clueless as to how to achieve this in MySQL, or even if its possible. I haven't tried anything yet as I have no idea where to even start.

I should say that the order of integers that aren't 2 is not a concern, so the following table is equally good.

```
-----------------------------------
  PK       integer          date
-----------------------------------
  1          2             01/01/01
  5          2             03/01/01      
  2          1             04/01/01
  6          1             06/01/01
  3          3             02/01/01
  4          3             05/01/01
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can order the query by a calculated expression, e.g., `case`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `my_table`
ORDER BY CASE `integer` WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, `date` ASC
```

Comment: +1, first person to respond with a working solution using a CASE statement

Comment: i like this answer best as its the most flexible +1

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is subtract your `integer` by 2 and then get the absolute value of that number.  Then sort on that.  The absolute value of 2 - 2 will always be zero and any other calculation will be greater than zero.  therefor you will be forcing `integer`s of 2 to the top of the list ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a53128/2/0)):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY ABS(`integer` - 2), `date`
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The date isn't ordered. Ive modified question slightly to help you understand

Comment: **@Gaz_Edge**, I modifed my answer to sort by date secondary

Comment: While this is a clever solution for integers up to 3, it starts to go wonky after that:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3988dc/1 (I added `thesort` to show what's going on)

Comment: **@Digital Chris**, correct it definitely would not work for any `integer` greater than 3.  Based on **Gaz_Edge** sample data I went with this clear cut answer since there was no `integer` greater than 3.  If `integer`s greater than 3 are used **Mureinik** answer or yours would work.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this with a UNION was trickier than I first thought, but you can specify a priority:

```
SELECT 1 as priority, id, mynumber, date from myTable
WHERE mynumber = 2

UNION

SELECT 2, id, mynumber, date from myTable
WHERE mynumber <> 2

ORDER BY priority ASC, date ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/570be/16

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Dates aren't ordered. I have modified question as i think the dates were confusing people.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge day late and a dollar short, but there's another working solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to put the integers in order by their minimum date, if I understand the question correctly.

You need to calculate this field, join it in, and then use it for the ordering:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select `integer`, min(date) as mindate
      from t
      group by `integer`
     ) tm
     on tm.`integer` = t.`integer`
order by tm.mindate, integer;
```

You can see the results on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/621ee/2).

Comment: and what would this output? I don't think integer 2 would be on top.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge . . . See the current version.  The previous version had a mistake and the current version is tested.

Comment: *@Gordon Linoff*, looking at your SQL Fiddle the date is not ordered when the integer is other than 2.  You have ***January, 05 2001*** ahead of ***January, 04 2001***.

Comment: @Linger . . . That is because Jan 5th has the integer value of "3".  It is ordered by the minimum date of the integers.

Answer (score 2):

do it easily by this

EDIT:

```
   select * from Table1
   order by case when `integer` != 2 then `date` end asc ,
            case when `integer` = 2 then `date` end asc ;
```

[**SECOND_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88a5a/14)

Comment: Doesn't work. I have slightly modified question as i think the dates were confusing people

Comment: @Gaz_Edge edited my answer try it now my second edit and second demo

Comment: @Gaz_Edge it works also good in your last fiddle here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3988dc/6